# How to contact an investor for a business?

Tags: starting-out-investing, start-up

I  recently opened a startup and I am  preparing a well-crafted presentation of my idea for potential investors.

I have to admit that I really don't  know how to contact them. Finding them is difficult and even when identified, I don't know how to reach them. I feel like an investor is a one shot opportunity in that if I send them an email and they don't reply, the opportunity is gone.

What is the  best approach to contact an investor? Is it just  sending  an email with a few words? An email with an attached abstract? And what if that investor is a foundation?

I sent an email to a foundation but I never got a reply. Perhaps they didn't read the email or perhaps they  read it but didn't review the attached abstract. Is there anyone  who would like to share useful strategies/methods for  contacting an investor as well as the best way to frame the discourse?

Comment: Your problem is not contacting. Seriously, if you do not know how to write an email or send a letter or make a phone call - you should not open a startup but be iunder guardianship. Your problem is FINDING investors. "It happened to me to send an email to a foundation" - ONE (!) data point is statistically exactly one thing: TOTALLY IRRELEVANT. Send emails to 200 foundations and then you get relevant data.

Comment: @TomTom, so you suggest to go for the big-numbers/low-chance strategy rather than studying the market and selecting the most appropriate investors? I would be very pissed off if I was to receive a pre-compiled standard cold-contact email. So, to appropriately edit 200 emails, it would mean to me at least 2 months of intensive work. All this just to rely on chance, which is not actually my usual approach, but I can do that. My question anyway was more on style: different categories may be preferring different approaches.

Comment: Well, many years ago when I learned being a broker, I was told to call 50 leads every day to be successfull. Finding investors is HARD WORK - not "i sent an email, now I swim in money". Start contacting every possible one.